# How can I set individual ToolTips for each StackPanel item?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, tooltip, stackpanel

I'm relatively new to WPF, and am using a Stackpanel to display a list of images. This list of images is dynamic, so the Stackpanel items are added at run-time in code, rather than directly in the XAML.

I was curious then as to how I would manage to display individual tooltips for each image in the `Stackpanel`. I was thinking I could do something as follows:

```
private void mainTaskBar_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Image img in imgList)
        if (img == e.OriginalSource)
            displayCorrespondingTooltip(img);
}
```

But this seems a bit excessive to have to do. Is there any way you could simply get a list of the children in the stackpanel and simply set each individual ToolTip with `SetToolTip()`? I feel like that would be much more elegant.

Thanks!

Comment: The "right" WPF way to do this would be to have an ObservableCollection of your items bound to the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl, with an ItemTemplate that displays your image, with tooltip, etc. Not that you should rewrite everything now that it's working! But it's a very easy and powerful way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method like the following to assign tooltip for various controls:

```
public void displayCorrespondingTooltip<T>(T control, string tooltipText)
    {
       //For images
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(Image))
        {
            (control as Image).ToolTip = tooltipText;
        }
       //For Rectangles
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
        {
            (control as Rectangle).ToolTip = tooltipText;
        }
    }
```

And this van be called like The following:

```
displayCorrespondingTooltip<Image>(img, "This will be the image tooltip");
displayCorrespondingTooltip<Rectangle>(rectObject,"rectangle tooltip");
```

Comment: Ohhh I see. So I can just add the tooltips and settings I want to each control before even adding it to the stackpanel! Thanks very much :)